# WCF Logging: Client is not getting the response

Tags: c#, wcf

Client is requesting a data from server and on the server side everything is working fine. Server is returning everything asked by client. But Client is not getting anything back. Eventually it times out. There is no exception on the server. 
I wish I could put some code here, but it is too complicated. I want to ask you guys if you faced similar issue? How can I figure out what is the problem? Is there way if I can see what WCF is doing behind the scene? I tried sticking this piece of code in to my app.config but it is not dumping the log file into a shown location. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\logs\TracingAndLogging-service.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="xml" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try reproducing it with a small sample application. Without any concrete details, it is only guessing for us.

Comment: Unfortunately there are many reasons why this can happen. In the past I have enabled tracing and message logging. You can find a basic tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Bosman Thanks for the link. Let me try see if I can find anything there.

Comment: @wpf_starter np. Another suggestion is to create a console project that calls the client. Sometimes this can provide additional exception information compared to calling it in a web app. Here is a basic example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730144(v=vs.110).aspx hope that helps

Comment: @Bosman I added diagnostics stuff in to my app.config, but it is not generating the log into shown place in the app.config. Do I have to do it on serverside or client. Or maybe both.

Comment: You can also use Error for the switchValue to log only the errors: switchValue="Error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with logging. I had to create the logs folder. That's why it wasn't dumping the log file.